# Adding Model data supplied by a SOAP feed to a URL string

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

So I've got a bit of a puzzle on this one and unless I'm looking for the wrong thing on Google then I'm not drawing many answers.

So basically I'm trying to add a Google Maps function to my website which pre-completes a search query for the post code of the property.

I've got a piece of model data which already contains the postcode for the property and is how my results are populated with the data too.

However I want to place this at the end of a Google Maps query by having a user click on an image to do so. My code looks like this currently.

Javascript:

```
                <script>
                    var postCodeURL = {@Model.Postcode };
                    function addURL(element) {
                    $(element).attr('href', function () {
                    return this.href + (postCodeURL());
                        });
                            }
                </script>
```

My code in the view looks like this:

```
     <a onclick="addURL(this)" href="http://maps.google.co.uk?en&p=">
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/maps-bg.png")" alt="maps-bg" /></a>
                <div class="mask"></div>
                <p class="small">
                    @Model.Address1<br />@Model.Address2<br />@Model.Postcode
                </p>
```

I read somewhere I need to serialize this data in order to post it into the URL. But not quite sure how I achieve this.. Or if that's even correct.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: If you just need to pass as querystring , means `GET` request, so you don't have to go for `serialization` and hence just append `..&p=` to required value.

Comment: Thank you @ArindamNayak. Worked perfectly. Please submit it as an answer to so I can declare this solved etc.

Comment: added this as answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to pass as querystring , means `GET` request, so you don't have to go for serialization and hence just append `..&p=` to required value.